# Массив объектов, сложение по одинаковым элементам внутри

Tags: javascript

имеется

```
let arr = [{idBox: "15", id: 13, price: 8805},
{idBox: "6", id: 14, price: 4467},
{idBox: "6", id: 15, price: 18853},
{idBox: "7", id: 16, price: 5649},
{idBox: "7", id: 17, price: 3645},
{idBox: "7", id: 18, price: 2505},
{idBox: "7", id: 19, price: 4397},
{idBox: "8", id: 20, price: 5548},
{idBox: "8", id: 21, price: 3645},
{idBox: "8", id: 22, price: 3645}]
```

Не могу придумать каким образом сложить элементы price с одинаковыми значениями 
    idBox, что бы конечный вариант был как пример

```
{idBox: "6", id: 14, price: (здесь сумма одинаковых idBox(4467 + 18853))},
{idBox: "6", id: 15, price: (здесь сумма одинаковых idBox)}
```

либо новый массив объектов типа [{idBox: "6", price:сумма одинаковых элементов}]

Comment: `reduce` используйте

Answer (score 1):

Можно вот так. В результате объект с одержащий ключи - idBox : значение -  сумму его price

```
let res = Object.fromEntries(arr.map(item => [item.idBox, 0]));
arr.forEach(item => {res[item.idBox] += item.price})
```

Ссылка на [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/juqkbcha/)

Comment: Спасибо, правильный вариант, ранее я пытался через reduce и несколько не удачно, сумма высчитывалась неверно

Comment: @user348720 обратите внимание на поддержку данного функционала браузерами

Comment: с этим проблем нет, сборщик всё переварит

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать `Array.reduce`

```js
const  arr = [{idBox: "15", id: 13, price: 8805},
              {idBox: "6", id: 14, price: 4467},
              {idBox: "6", id: 15, price: 18853},
              {idBox: "7", id: 16, price: 5649},
              {idBox: "7", id: 17, price: 3645},
              {idBox: "7", id: 18, price: 2505},
              {idBox: "7", id: 19, price: 4397},
              {idBox: "8", id: 20, price: 5548},
              {idBox: "8", id: 21, price: 3645},
              {idBox: "8", id: 22, price: 3645}];
              
              
let result = arr.reduce((a,c) => (a[c.idBox] = (a[c.idBox] || 0) + c.price, a), {});              
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Это не корректный ответ, когда я пытался сделать сам у меня было 
`let t = arr.reduce((sum, arrs) => {
  sum[arrs.idBox] = sum[arrs.idBox]? arrs.price+arrs.price: arrs.price
  return sum
}, {})

console.log(t)`
собственно на этом я и споткнулся, поскольку просто задваивал первое подвернувшееся значение, вместо сложения всех имеющихся

Comment: @user348720 пардоньте, скобки удалил перед отправкой. вернул на место. все путем вроде.

Comment: @user348720 а ваша ошибка была в `arrs.price+arrs.price` хотя надо было `arrs.price + sum[arrs.idBox]`

Comment: спасибо, я уже сам через reduce сделал, на основе вашего решения ))

Comment: единственный момент, который если можно поясните пожалуйста подробнее, правильно ли я понял, что при одинаковом ключе у нас складываются значения и этим фокусом мы и пользуемся что бы всё сработало? Ранее я с этим не встречался поэтому хотелось бы уточнить всё из первых уст )

Comment: @user348720 если ключа нет, то на первой итерации `a[c.idBox]` будет `undefined`. Поэтому мы делаем `|| 0`, что для первой итерации даст нам начальный 0. После уже к нему мы прибавляем текущее значение цены. То есть обычная формула сумма+текущий, но с исправлением начальной несуществующей суммы на 0.

Answer (score 0):

Наговнокодил =) зато просто и понятно

```
var arr2 = new Object
for(a in arr)
{
  arr2[arr[a].idBox] =(!!arr2[arr[a].idBox]) + arr[a].price
}
```